Why doesn't a raw pointer and a smart pointer unique_ptr that are pointing to the same resource causes any issues? (C++)
I know that unique_ptr makes the smart pointer own the resource and thus it doesn't allow multiple pointers to point to the same resource.
But why then is it allowed to create a raw pointer of that smart pointer with .get() and then pass it to a function?
At the end you have two pointers that have ownership of the resource and with the ability to change its value? Which would violate the rule of unique_ptr smart ptr exclusively owning the resource.
In the example below I made a simple program that changes the value that the smrt pointer  smrtPtr is pointing at.
Ex:
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility> //move semantics

void changeValue(int* ptr)
{
    if (!ptr)       //check if pointer is null
        return;
    *ptr = 17;       //change value to 17
}



int main()
{

    auto smrtPtr{ std::make_unique<int>(5) };
 
    changeValue(smrtPtr.get());    //creates a raw pointer of smrtPtr

    if (smrtPtr)            //if it does contain resource
        std::cout << *smrtPtr;

        return 0;
}

Thanks a lot

Raw pointers imply NO ownership. That is both their beauty and their curse.

Important reading: What is ownership of resources or pointers?

thanks a lot, but for example smart pointer of std::weak_ptr also doesn't own the resource, yet it's not allowed for it to share the same resource with one smart pointer of std::unique_ptr?

In order to get the pointer out of a weak_ptr you have to get a shared_ptr from the weak_ptr, if you can, and then get the pointer from the shared_ptr. If you took that pointer and then placed it in a unique_ptr you now have conflicting owners: the unique_ptr will free the resource when it goes out of scope and the last shared_ptr will also free the resource. At best, the program suffers a double free, but you would be unlucky to get that far. A raw pointer only frees a resource when you explicitly call delete on it.

@tadm123 weak_ptr doesn't make sense because it does participate in the ownership semantics.  The way it hooks into that is the control block that is created in making a shared_ptr.  Since nothing else should share in the ownership of a unique_ptr is is 100% okay to return a raw pointer as a handle.

Note that if you get a shared_ptr from a weak_ptr, that shared_ptr is just as much an owner as any other linked shared_ptrs. The reason for this is to make sure that as long as you hold the shared_ptr you got from the weak_ptr, there is at least one shared_ptr instance keeping the owned resource alive. No one else can free it out from beneath you unless they do something really ing stupid like manually delete it.

To sum up, you don't have two owning pointers because the raw pointer does not own. Both the smart pointer and the raw pointer can change and make use of the referred-to resource because neither are ownership behaviours. Only the smart pointer is allowed to act like an owner and free the referred to resource without bad consequences.

"and thus it doesn't allow multiple pointers to point to the same resource." it does no such thing.   It means that smart pointer is the sole OWNER of the resource and therefor the sole responsibility to determine when to delete it.   It has nothing to do with who can look at the contents.

@tadm123 "smart pointer of std::weak_ptr also doesn't own the resource" -- This is true enough; a weak_ptr sort of leases the resource instead of owning it. It has an agreement that gives it access to the resource for as long as the resource is around. However, it is the owners, not the lessees, who decide when the resource is disposed of. If the resource is gone and the lessee wants it, the lessee is told "too bad". Note that, by design, unique_ptrs do not lease their resources in this way.

@tadm123 a lot of things you're saying "aren't allowed" should be said are "not correct" but that doesn't mean a bad program can't do them.

There are usually two factors that make people stumble with the "smart pointers"; 1) they think about them as pointers rather than objects with specific ownership rules, and 2) they have never really thought about the nature of ownership. (Consider how many things around you have a specific owner which isn't you, and yet you're able to view and even make use of it.)

"with the ability to change its value" That is constness, which is unrelated to ownership.

Your entire question is based on confusion of what a smart pointer does:

"and thus it doesn't allow multiple pointers to point to the same resource."

It does no such thing.   A smart pointer determines who OWNS the resource, not who can view the resource.
The responsibility of the owner is to delete the resource at the correct time.   This means not deleting it before other things are done reading it.
A unique pointer means it is the only thing responsible for deletion.   A shared pointer means that the last shared pointer around is responsible for deletion.
None of this impacts the ability to access the resource.

The standard terminology is "ownership", but I can see how that is somewhat inaccurate. In the real world, it is often the case that the owner of something is the only one who can change that something. (For example, most homeowners would be upset if someone cam by and painted their home a new color.) This is not what "ownership" means with regards to memory management.
A more accurate term might be "custodian". A custodian's job is to take care of something. There is no implication that the "something" is exclusively the custodian's, only that it falls to the custodian to see that things are taken care of, such as cleaning up at the end of the day. Which brings us back to memory management. The "custodian" (usually called "owner") is responsible for cleaning up memory. The timing of the cleanup is up to the custodian, with one caveat. If there is more than one custodian (think shared_ptr), there is an agreement that the cleanup falls to the last custodian to leave. (Custodian 1: "I'm headed home. You'll lock up, right?" Custodian 2: "Yeah, I'm on it.")
When a pointer is obtained from a smart pointer via get(), that pointer provides access to the stored object. It can be permitted to modify–but not destroy–the object with this access. Analogously, access to a meeting room often includes permission to rearrange–but not damage–the chairs. And maybe hang posters or other visual aids. The point is that changes can be made. After the meeting, the attendees leave and the custodian locks up, ending all permitted access. This is the role of the smart pointer, to lock up / end permitted access when there is no longer a custodian around.
(The reason for qualifying with "permitted" is explained by the hotel story. It is possible to get locked in the meeting room and have forbidden access. If the environment does not decide to demolish the place overnight.)

Still, it's a bit late to change the terminology. We're stuck with "owner", but if it helps to think "custodian", go for it.
